# how to compare a value from a factor

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df1`, out of which I am trying to fetch the unique values from a column "parameter" which in turn giving me a "factor"

I want to create an `if` condition like

```
if (unique(df1$parameterName) == "effectivetemp"){
   print('yes')
}
```

by doing this it says

> Warning message:
>        In if (as.factor(unique(Daily_Avg_Count$parameterName)) == 
>        "cteffectiveness") { :
>        the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Please show what you really wanted.  Is it just to print 'yes', then `if('effectivetemp' %in% unique(df1$parameterName)) print("yes")`  where `df1 <- data.frame(parameterName = c('a', 'b', 'effectivetemp'))`